# What is Router Middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, router

Hello guys I am new in express framework
I need clear  explaining about Router middleware , I have looking for it in doc but there no answer

Comment: does this help? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1):

A node js basic server listen for (http/https) request and forward those to a handler, so basicly you have one javascript function as the only entrypoint of all your requests.

Middlewares are features added on top of his basic handler, in the form of a stack of functions that take this request into a pipeline doing stuff with it (logging, parsing body, security ...ect).

Router is one of those middleware, what it does actualy is to take the original request, and forward it to a sub handler according to the path example : "/home" for a GET request is mapped to function getHome that handle it and eventually send a response to the client on the behalf of the original handler.

Answer (score 0):

Routing defines the way in which the client requests are handled by the application endpoints.
And when you make some routers in separate file, you can use them by using middleware.

Comment: you mean i can't using this middleware in same file

Answer (score 0):

The term is composed of 2 words `router` and `middleware`

> **Middleware**

It is a piece of code that comes in the middle of `request` and `response`. It kind of hijacks your request so that you can do anything that you want with your `request` or `response` eg: Modify the data or call the next middleware. Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle

> **Router**

In Express, usually, we make end-points that uses [HTTP verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to denote a `GET` `POST` `DELETE` `PUT` etc requests. `Router` is used to manage these incoming requests. It kind of routes your requests to correct handler/code

Checkout [this article](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-node-js-middleware-works-d8e02a936113#:%7E:text=A%20middleware%20is%20basically%20a,once%20your%20middleware%20code%20completed.) for more